# Control of the combinatorial aspects of a dynamic programming solution

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, combinatorics, memoization

I am exploring how a Dynamic Programming design approach relates to the underlying combinatorial properties of problems.

For this, I am looking at the canonical instance of the **coin exchange problem**: Let `S = [d_1, d_2, ..., d_m]` and `n > 0` be a requested amount. In how many ways can we add up to `n` using nothing but the elements in `S`?

If we follow a **Dynamic Programming** approach to design an algorithm for this problem that would allow for a solution with polynomial complexity, we would start by looking at the problem and how it is related to smaller and simpler sub-problems. This would yield a **recursive relation** describing an inductive step representing the problem in terms of the solutions to its related subproblems. We can then implement either a **memoization** technique or a **tabulation** technique to efficiently implement this recursive relation in a **top-down** or a **bottom-up** manner, respectively.

A recursive relation could be the following (Python 3.6 syntax and 0-based indexing):

```
def C(S, m, n):
    if n < 0:
        return 0
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if m <= 0:
        return 0
    count_wout_high_coin = C(S, m - 1, n)
    count_with_high_coin = C(S, m, n - S[m - 1])
    return count_wout_high_coin + count_with_high_coin
```

However, when drawing the sub-problem DAG, one can see that any DP-based algorithm implementing this recursive relation would yield a correct amount of solutions but disregarding the order.

For example, for `S = [1, 2, 6]` and `n = 6`, one can identify the following ways (assumming *order matters*):

1. `1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1`
2. `2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1`
3. `1 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1`
4. `1 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 1`
5. `1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 1`
6. `1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2`
7. `2 + 2 + 1 + 1`
8. `1 + 2 + 2 + 1`
9. `1 + 1 + 2 + 2`
10. `2 + 1 + 2 + 1`
11. `1 + 2 + 1 + 2`
12. `2 + 1 + 1 + 2`
13. `2 + 2 + 2`
14. `6`

Assumming order does not matter, we could count the following solutions:

1. `1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1`
2. `2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1`
3. `2 + 2 + 1 + 1`
4. `2 + 2 + 2`
5. `6`

When approaching a problem solution from the Dynamic Programming standpoint, how can I control the order? Specifically, how could I write functions:

- `count_with_order()`
- `count_wout_order()`

?

Could it be that the need for order mattering implies choosing pruned backtracking over a Dynamic Programming approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each problem is idiosyncratic, although there may be some problems that could be grouped together. For your particular example, a count where order matters could be implemented (either recursed or tabulated) by considering that the number of solutions for `n` is equal to the total of solutions achievable from each lower achievable number, that is `n - coin` for each denomination.

Python code:

```py
def f(n, coins):
  if n < 0:
    return 0

  if n == 0:
    return 1

  return sum([f(n - coin, coins) for coin in coins])

# => f(6, [1, 2, 6]) # 14
```

Comment: This is a great answer, and it definitely shows how the combinatorial aspect of order can be taken into consideration within a DP approach :)

Comment: I am also studying the parity of the summands in the solutions. Say I want to split `n` among 2 persons s.t. each person gets the same number of coins, regardless of the total sum each gets. From the 14 solutions, only 7 include an even number of coins so that I can split them evenly. But I want to exclude redundant assignments of coins to each person. For example, `1+2+2+1` and `1+2+1+2` are different solutions when order matters, BUT they represent the same split of coins to two persons, i.e. person B would get `1+2 = 2+1`. I am having a hard time coming up with a recursion to count splits.

Comment: At first, I thought that counting the solutions with an even number of summands from the grand total would yield the correct count of non-redundant splits, BUT I can see now that this reasoning is not correct.

Comment: @Eduardo thank you for your comments. Perhaps post a question with a bit more detail about the splits you are describing. It sounds interesting.

Comment: @Eduardo also consider adding the `algorithm` tag.